# GridView w/ model binding UpdateMethod not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, model-binding

I have a basic Web Forms project using Entity Frameworks & SQL Server for data.  I'm trying to connect a GridView to a table and for some reason the UpdateMethod does not get called.  It does a postback when the "Update" link is clicked but it never gets to the gvNames_UpdateItem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNames" runat="server" SelectMethod="gvNames_GetData" UpdateMethod="gvNames_UpdateItem"
    DeleteMethod="gvNames_DeleteItem" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true" ItemType="CountyPMFraudData.NotifyName" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="NotifyNamesID" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnPreRender="gvNames_PreRender" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="NotifyNamesID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="UserID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="CorpFlag" HeaderText="Business" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="FirstName" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name/Business Name" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
public void gvNames_DeleteItem(int notifyNamesID)
{
    using (var dbContext = new CountyPMFraudEntities())
    {
        var item = new NotifyName { NotifyNamesID = notifyNamesID };
        dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        try
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            ValidationError.Display(String.Format("Item with id {0} no longer exists in the database.", notifyNamesID));
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable gvNames_GetData()
{
    List<NotifyName> names = null;

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {                

        using (var dbContext = new CountyPMFraudEntities())
        {
            names = dbContext.NotifyNames.Where(NotifyName => NotifyName.UserID == _userID).ToList();
        }
    }

    return names;
}

public void gvNames_UpdateItem(int notifyNamesID)
{

    using (var dbContext = new CountyPMFraudEntities())
    {
        var name = dbContext.NotifyNames.Find(notifyNamesID);

        if (name == null)
        {                    
            ValidationError.Display(String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", notifyNamesID));
            return;
        }

        TryUpdateModel(name);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}

protected void gvNames_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gvNames.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Just ignore becuase there is no data.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  Two things were going on.  First I missed adding a "ValidationSummary" and enabling ShowModelStateErrors like this:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsHuman" ShowModelStateErrors="true" ValidationGroup="vgHuman" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Once I did that then I realized I was getting an error "The NotifyNamesID field is required.".  With this I discovered for some reason the hidden "DynamicField" did not contain the data when going back to the server, so I had to change it to a TemplateField like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("NotifyNamesID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Once I did this things began to work.  Hope this helps somebody in the future.